# Syntax: chaining model to i18n in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller, internationalization

Inside my `galleries#index` I have a translation setup,

```
<%= t"galleries.sorter.country" %>
<%= t"galleries.sorter.project" %>
<%= t"galleries.sorter.theme" %>
```

I want to dynamically replace the last part of the translation since one of my model's attribute has all the terms. My :gallery has a `tag` attribute that stores strings like country, project, and theme

I have in my controller an action `@galleries = Gallery.all.order("title")` and planning to use `each` method to loop them out.

Some thing like `t"galleries.sorter'.gallery.tag'"`(the .gallery.tag part suppose to be from the model) How to I do it right syntactically?

Answer (score 1):

See [I18n Interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation). E.g. in the locale file:

```
galleries_sorter: 'Hello world and %{tag}'
```

Then call for the translation while passing in the variable part like this:

```
<% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
  <%= t(:galleries_sorter, tag: gallery.tag) %>
<% end %>
```